# Complements / intersection of two generic array filled with NSIndexPath

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, generics

`ipsToReload.filter { !contains(self.ipsToInsert, {$0.row == $1.row}) }`

I want to get this expression work. I need complements of the two generic array: `ipsToReload` \ `ipsToInsert`. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

This is the definition:

```
var ipsToInsert = [NSIndexPath]()
var ipsToDelete = [NSIndexPath]()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is that you have two nested closure expressions (the one to `filter`, and the one to `contains`).  But within a closure expression, `$0` and `$1` refer to arguments local to that closure expression – so in this case, you are writing an expression for `contains` that takes two arguments (`$0` and `$1`), and then the closure argument to `filter` looks as if it takes no arguments (hence Swift is complaining that you can't pass a `()->_` argument into `filter`).

Try naming the arguments, like so:

```
ipsToReload.filter { reload in 
    !contains(ipsToInsert) { insert in 
        reload.row == insert.row 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Which version of Xcode/Swift are you running?  I just pasted this into a 6.3 playground and it runs ok for me.